# oracle server version error from asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle

Please help me to resolve this problem. im getting server version error when trying to connect to database to execute oracle function from mvc application.

```
    public ActionResult ApplicationSearch(string applicationNo)
    {
        var totalBond = OracleCommand("bond.GET_TOTALBOND");
        totalBond.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        totalBond.Parameters.Add("PBONDSCN", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = applicationNo;
        totalBond.Parameters.Add("VCOUNT", OracleDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        //totalBond.Parameters["VCOUNT"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

        totalBond.Connection.Open();
        totalBond.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ViewBag.TotalBondInstallment = Convert.ToString(totalBond.Parameters["VCOUNT"].Value);
        totalBond.Connection.Close();

        var application = _context.BONDAPPLICATIONs.SingleOrDefault(a => a.BONDSCN.Equals(applicationNo));
        var model = new InstallmentPaymentViewModel()
        {
            Bondapplication = application
        };

        return View(model);
    }
    #endregion


    #region STORED PROCEDURE AREA

    public OracleConnection DatabaseConnection()
    {
        //var connection = new OracleConnection(_context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
        var connection = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BondModelDb"].ConnectionString);
        return connection;
    }

    public OracleCommand OracleCommand(string commandText)
    {
        var oracleCommand = new OracleCommand(commandText, DatabaseConnection());
        return oracleCommand;
    }
```

im getting this error from DatabaseConnection() method:

ServerVersion = 'connection.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Comment: Check your connection string inside `BondModelDb` key in web.config, is it correct?

Comment: connection string seems working. when connection is open server version error is gone.but still not getting any output from function.TotalBondInstallment  is always null. no error is thrown.any help.am i missing something??   <connectionStrings>    <add name="BondModelDb" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=******;Password=*****;Data Source=10.10.7.30:1521/bond" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Since `ViewBag.TotalBondInstallment` always assigned as null, can you show error message and stack trace of thrown `InvalidOperationException` and have you want to get return value or output parameter value from stored procedure named `bond.GET_TOTALBOND` (better to provide stored procedure code in your question)?